# Newtonsoft JArray ToString double quotes in ASP.NET MVC razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, json.net

I have created a `JArray` list:

```
JArray branchesJson = new JArray();
```

Then while I am iterating using a foreach I add objects to the list like:

```
// Add branch to the json array
branchesJson.Add(new JObject
{
    {"name", branch.Name},
    {"lat", branchDetails.Lat},
    {"long", branchDetails.Long}
});
```

This is all done in razor on a view. Now I need this output added to my javascript which is in the same view at the bottom in a seperated section.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            'use strict';

            var locations = @branchesJson.ToString();

            alert(JSON.stringify(locations));

        });
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
}
```

Then using the `.ToString()` method I get an output like:

```
[
  {
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Brugge&quot;,
    &quot;lat&quot;: &quot;51.246701&quot;,
    &quot;long&quot;: &quot;3.200326&quot;
  },
  {
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Destelbergen&quot;,
    &quot;lat&quot;: &quot;51.052056&quot;,
    &quot;long&quot;: &quot;3.761034&quot;
  },
  {
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Sint-Niklaas&quot;,
    &quot;lat&quot;: &quot;51.143114&quot;,
    &quot;long&quot;: &quot;4.171444&quot;
  },
  {
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Terneuzen&quot;,
    &quot;lat&quot;: &quot;51.301069&quot;,
    &quot;long&quot;: &quot;3.848187&quot;
  },
  {
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Vlissingen&quot;,
    &quot;lat&quot;: &quot;51.472778&quot;,
    &quot;long&quot;: &quot;3.592411&quot;
  }
]
```

This gives errors in the error console.

When I use the replace function `.Replace("&quot;", "\"")` it still showes me the `&quot;` instead of the `"`.

Comment: whats the value of `locations` before the `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Like in my question, the alert is not shown because of the error in the error console on the `quot;` issue

Comment: right, look at the generated HTML and see what happens at the `var locations = ` line

Comment: Also shown with `quot;` instead of `"`

Comment: try surrounding that line in single quotes: `var locations = '@branchesJson.ToString()';` so that it stores the json as string instead of trying to parse it as javascript.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Try this `var locations = unescape('@branchesJson.ToString()');`

Comment: Have you tried using Html.Raw? `var locations = @Html.Raw(branchesJson.ToString());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Html.Raw` like this:

```
var locations = @Html.Raw(branchesJson.ToString());
```

[Here there is some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx):

> Wraps HTML markup in an HtmlString instance so that it is interpreted
>   as HTML markup.